# Nsis: Problem in FileRead

Tags: file-io, nsis

When I read a file using FileRead and display the contents in a listbox I get some garbage characters after the line.

Eg. if my line is : a.txt

```
I get something lk: a.txt$$
```

(Note $$ are some garbage characters)
Its probably because of $\r$\n. What can I do to correct this?

Comment: I can't see garbage characters in your question, can you edit to make them visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [TrimNewLines](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/AppendixE.html#E.2.14) helper macro